# Выровнять input'ы

Tags: html, css

Как (грамотно/толково) выровнять радио **input**'ы, чтобы они ровно все по центру были, а не вразброс:

```
<table class="common" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="100" valign="top"><a href="#">link</a></td>
        <td align="center" width="800"><img src="#" width="120" height="100" style="margin-top: 30px;" /></td>
        <td align="right" valign="top" width="100">link</td>
    </tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><b>1.</b></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><img class="pogon" width="400" src="#" height="200"/></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
            <div class="rovno" align="center">
                <input type="radio" name="choise" value="unos"/>unos<br />
                <input type="radio" name="choise" value="dos"/>dos<br />
                <input type="radio" name="choise" value="tres"/>tres<br />
                <input type="radio" name="choise" value="quatro"/>quatro
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3" align="center"><button>value</button></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>

/* style welcome +table */
table.common { width: 100%; }
div.rovno { text-align: center; width: 50%; border: 1px solid; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*вот такое свойство делает чудеса* **margin: 0px auto;**

```
<div class="rovno" style="margin: 0px auto; text-align: left;">
   <input type="radio" name="choise" value="unos"/>unos<br />
   <input type="radio" name="choise" value="dos"/>dos<br />
   <input type="radio" name="choise" value="tres"/>tres<br />
   <input type="radio" name="choise" value="quatro"/>quatro
</div>
```

Comment: При чём тут margin? Просто было выравнивание по центру, а Вы поставили по левому краю (text-align: left;)

Answer (score 1):

```
/* style welcome +table */
table.common { width: 100%; }
.rovno {width: 10%; border: 1px solid; text-align: left}
```

Comment: Хорошая статья про выравнивание по центру: http://habrahabr.ru/post/144378/

Answer (score 0):

<div class="rovno" align="center">

```
        <table>

        <tr>

            <td><input type="radio" name="choise" value="unos"></td><td>unos</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><input type="radio" name="choise" value="dos"/></td><td>dos</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><input type="radio" name="choise" value="tres"/></td><td>tres</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><input type="radio" name="choise" value="quatro"></td><td>quatro</td>

        </tr>

        </table>

        </div>
```